# Bootstrap 4 JavaScript not working Symfony4

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, symfony4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 in Symfony 4 using yarn package manager but somehow the JavaScript is not working. I have no errors in the console but when I try to trigger the navbar collapsed button I won't open the navbar.

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

require("bootstrap/js/dist/");
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/app.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CRM Fabriek</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I compiled the js to the build/js/app.js file by using `yarn run encore dev`

Comment: Did you find a solution ? My collapse divs also dont work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import Bootstrap’s JavaScript by adding this line to your app’s entry point (usually index.js or app.js):

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

or indicate the path completely

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

or if you prefer require()

```
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
```

Alternatively, you may import plugins individually as needed:

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
...
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript

In the webpack-encore documentation says that you must in your webpack.config.js file add a call .autoProvidejQuery() because Bootstrap expects jQuery to be available as a global variable.

```
// webpack.config.js
Encore
// ...
.autoProvidejQuery();
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html#importing-bootstrap-javascript